# load content via jquery ajax after php output is complete

Tags: php, jquery, post

I am currently using jquery ajax to POST data to a php file which uses that data to build and output a jQuery-based gallery.

the "links" that are clicked on to trigger the ajax are:

```
<li class="portfolioLink" id="identity">identity</li>
<li class="portfolioLink" id="mobile">mobile</li>
<li class="portfolioLink" id="web">web</li>
```

and a sample of the jQuery ajax is:

```
$("#identity").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'portfolio.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: ({data: 'portfolio/design/identityDesign/*'}),
        success: function(data){
        $("#content_middle").html(data);
        }
    });
    $("#identity").addClass('active');
    $(".portfolioLink:not(#identity)").removeClass('active')
});
```

(this jquery is basically iterated 2 more times with different data:)

This is working fine, except that the output of portfolio.php (the gallery builder) is loaded into #content_middle as the output's JavaScript is being processed (so it looks like the gallery is being built live in #content_middle). Seeing it happen will probably make more sense: [www.frende.me/design.php](http://www.frende.me/design.php)

What I want to happen is for the gallery to load fully built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you hide the element, add the new html to it and show it again? Like this:

```
$("#identity").click(function(){     
    $.ajax({         
        url: 'portfolio.php',         
        type: "POST",         
        data: ({data: 'portfolio/design/identityDesign/*'}),         
        success: function(data){ 
            $("#content_middle").hide();       
            $("#content_middle").html(data);         
            $("#content_middle").show();
        }     
    });     
$("#identity").addClass('active');     
$(".portfolioLink:not(#identity)").removeClass('active') });
```

Comment: btw, you must have `();` after `$("#content_middle").show` or it doesn't work ;)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you would like to have the content appear completely once the page loads. Unfortunately the page is returned as soon as the DOM is created. So images will be considered constructed, but that does not mean that their src has been loaded.

Try using a image preloader like this [one](http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-image-preload-plugin/)

Hope this helps, otherwise comment if you need more details.

Comment: oh cool. i think the preloader might do it for me.

but to clarify, the issue isn't really that the images aren't loaded yet, it's that the css and javascript are being applied as the content is loaded in and i want it to load with the css & javascript already done.

thanks!

Comment: @megaperiz actually posted how to do what i was asking for, but i think i'll use a combination of both your solutions. thanks to you both!